# "sudo ppa-purge ppa" failed with "Warning: Could not find package list for PPA:"

Tags: 20.04, ppa, purge

I am trying to ppa-purge
`agornostal/ulauncher`,
`apandada1/brightness-controller` and
`linuxuprising/shutter`

packages which I listed using
`find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done` command.

But when I try to run the following commands

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:agornostal/ulauncher`
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:apandada1/brightness-controller`
`sudo ppa-purge ppa:linuxuprising/shutter`

It fails with following Warning
`Updating packages lists PPA to be removed: agornostal ulauncher Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: agornostal ulauncher`

How can I use "ppa-purge" on these?

---

```
$ aptitude search ~o

i asbru-cm - A free and open-source connection manager 
i A containerd.io - An open and reliable container runtime 
i docker-ce - Docker: the open-source application contai 
i A docker-ce-cli - Docker CLI: the open-source application co 
i A docker-ce-rootless-extras - Rootless support for Docker. 
i vault - A tool for secrets management, encryption
```

Comment: Please add output of `grep "^deb\ .*ppa" -r /etc/apt/ --include=*.list` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1338194/edit).

Comment: I have removed these by deleting the .list files from /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory.

Comment: @N0rbert After removing these manually, my output for your command is empty

Comment: Now you may have locally installed packages from this PPAs. To be sure check the output of `aptitude search ~o` (install aptitude first if not installed).

Comment: i   asbru-cm                        - A free and open-source connection manager 
i A containerd.io                   - An open and reliable container runtime                   
i   docker-ce                       - Docker: the open-source application contai
i A docker-ce-cli                   - Docker CLI: the open-source application co
i A docker-ce-rootless-extras       - Rootless support for Docker.                            
i   vault                           - A tool for secrets management, encryption

Comment: All is good. I would recommend to write an answer about actually done steps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` had a different hostname.  That is, it had:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/PROJECT/stable/ubuntu jammy main
```

instead of:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/PROJECT/stable/ubuntu jammy main
#                       ^^^^^^^
```

I've added the `content` part, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after some research,

Step 1:
Listing items using following comand
`find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done`

Step 2
Direct to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` folder.

Step 3
Remove all results got from the 1st command in this folder path

Comment: its not clear exactly what you meant. but I tried removing everything else but the one I want to purge. and also everything. so the command on step 1 return only the one I want to purge or nothing at all. but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I found an additional method at Ubunutu Forums. I was having the same issue with `ppa-purge`, but the following method didn't give me any trouble.

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2282715&s=9b963fcf527d2bc3fd4a8681d2491087&p=13304774#post13304774

1. Open Software & Updates > Other
2. Look for and highlight the package you want to remove
3. Click "Remove"